# Conserve image background after adding PNG image in PHP

Tags: php, image, transparent

I'm trying to insert a PNG image with transparent background in another image with a grey background, but when I use imagecopymerge, I got black background, and with imagecopy, I got transparent places in the final image line in the picture above :

[image]

```
 imagecopymerge($image, $turquoise, 120, 120, 0, 0, 16, 16,100);
 imagecopy($image, $turquoise, 140, 140, 0, 0, 16, 16);
```

Even if I used or not :

```
 imagesavealpha($image, true);
 imagealphablending($image, true);
```

Comment: Are all of the assets images with an alpha channel?

Comment: is the file loaded into $turquoise either a png or gif? and how are your saving or returning the images?

Comment: $turquoise is PNG image and I used  imagecreatefrompng("data/turquoise.png") to load it :)

Comment: are you using imagecreatetruecolor to create the gray field in $image?

Comment: ImageFill($image, 0, 0, $grey229230232);